# Best way to handle API calls from frontend

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Okay, so atm i have a frontend application built with Nuxt JS using Axios to do requests to my REST API(separate).

If a user does a search on the website the API URL is visible in XMLHttprequests so everyone could use the API if they want to.

What is the best way of making it so that only users that search through my website gets access to the API and people that just directly to the URL gets denied. I suppose using some sort of token system, but what is the best way to do it? JWT? (Users never log in so there is no "authentication")

Thanks!

Comment: so, basically you want to ensure people is accessing your API using a browser, if that's the case I have bad news for you, people always find a way to bypass that if they want to, using something like reCAPTCHA is a way for ensuring a real user is accessing your API.

Comment: Well, i'd like a way to somehow restrict access to the API one way or another. Could IP restriction be a way as i am hosting the frontend on a separate port. So only allow direct calls from that port on the same machine(E.g API runs on port 5000, front end app on 5001. Could i say, only accept calls from 5000?

Comment: sure, you could isolate your API to receive calls from the front-end app only, then, how are you going to avoid giving access to non-browsers to your front-end?

Comment: Atleast the frontend only returns rendered components (SSR with Nuxt), so it makes it harder to get data i guess. You have to crawl the website then. But i guess, one way or another you can still get the data if you really want to. I just wanted to make it abit harder then just calling the api

Comment: as I said, you can't avoid it and just make it harder, one simple way for you is to place a reCAPTCHA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. IMO, you **CANNOT** block other illegal clients accessing your
   backend as you describe that the official client and other illegal have **the same knowledge** about your backend.
2. But you can make it harder for illegal clients to accessing your backend through some approach such as ***POST all requests***, ***special keys in header***, ***30-minutes-changed token in header*** and ***server-side API throttling by client IP***.
3. If the security of the search API is really important, authenticate it by login; if not, just let it go since it is not in your critical path. Let's focus on other important things.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think i'll do as you said and focus on other things. But i'll see if i can implement the key change in the header to make it a little bit harder for others to use. The main reason i am trying to secure it is beacuse some of the features on the backend does calls to service that has a request limit. So i want to make it as hard as possible to others to leech of my limit

Comment: Sure, you can try some middlewares/frameworks for request throttling.

Comment: Already have a throttle applied! I think i may just be abit to paranoid, is that a thing? :D

Comment: What is the "best" way, if there is any. To handle the header keys?

Comment: I was like you before. I understand you. But now, I will let the facts drive me to handle things. I suggest you concentrate handling other important functional requirements instead of the non-functional requirements which is not blocking you to go forward.

Comment: Some companies have their own so called best practices. I think there is no standard best way. If your website really has a security problem, I think it is good news which prove that your website get successful.

Comment: Thanks for the good response! I'll keep that in mind. I'll focus on the more important things driving me forward untill i actually feel like i need it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same "boat" and my current setup is actually in VueJs but before even come to StackOverflow I developed a way to actually, the frontend calls the server and then the server calls the API, so in the browser, you will only see calls to the server layer that, the only constraint is that the call must come from the same hostname.

backend is handled with expressJs and frontend with VueJs

```
// protect /api calls to only be originated from 'process.env.API_ALLOW_HOST'
app.use(api.allowOnlySameDomainRequests());

...

const allowHostname = process.env.API_ALLOW_HOST ||'localhost';

exports.api = {
    ...
    allowOnlySameDomainRequests: (req, res, next) => {
        if(req.url.startsWith('/api') && req.hostname === allowHostname) {
            // an /api call, only if request is the same
            return next();
        } else if (!req.url.startsWith('/api')) {
            // not an /api call
            return next();
        }

        return res.redirect('/error?code=401');
    },
    ...
};
```

In our case, we use Oauth2 (Google sign through passportJs) to log in the user, I always have a user id that was given by the OAuth2 successful redirect and that user id is passed to the API in a header, together with the apikey... in the server I check for that userid permissions and I allow or not the action to be executed.

But even I was **trying to find something better**. I've seen several javascript frontend apps using calls to their backend but they use `Bearer` tokens.

As a curious user, you would see the paths to all the API and how they are composed, but in my case, you only see calls to the expressJs backend, and only there I forward to the real API... I don't know if that's just "more work", but seemed a bit more "secure" to approach the problem this way.